# Getting "Error during processing: (ArgumentError) invalid byte sequence in UTF-8" when checking "valid?" method from my model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, ruby-on-rails-4, encoding, model

I’m using Rails 4.2.7 with PostGres 9.5.  I’m getting a strange error when I check if my model is valid.  I have a name field, defined in my PostGres db as such …

```
 name              | character varying           |
```

However, when I save this value into my model (some things may not cut and paste right from my editor …)

```
Beth Ordu?±a
```

And then I run

```
      if !insert.valid?
```

on a model with the following validation rules

```
class MyObjectTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :my_object
  has_one :linked_my_object, class_name: 'MyObject'
  belongs_to :state
  belongs_to :country

  validates :time_in_ms, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }
  validates :age, numericality: { greater_than: 0 }, :allow_blank =>      validates :name, presence: true, unless: :first_name_last_name_empty_and_user_id_is_not?

  attr_accessor :name_city, :time_str, :hometown, :division, :age_group_rank_str, :gender_rank_str, :overall_rank_str
```

I get the error below …

```
Error during processing: (ArgumentError) invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:117:in `==='
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/blank.rb:117:in `blank?'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validator.rb:150:in `block in validate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validator.rb:148:in `validate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/validations/presence.rb:5:in `validate'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `public_send'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `block in make_lambda'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:182:in `block in conditional'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `block in call'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:504:in `call'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `__run_callbacks__'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_validate_callbacks'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validations.rb:399:in `run_validations!'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `block in run_validations!'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_validation_callbacks'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validations/callbacks.rb:113:in `run_validations!'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activemodel-4.2.7.1/lib/active_model/validations.rb:338:in `valid?'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:58:in `valid?'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:154:in `block (2 levels) in save_my_object_time_results'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:152:in `each'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:152:in `block in save_my_object_time_results'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:149:in `save_my_object_time_results'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_import_service.rb:92:in `process_my_object_data'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/active_com_my_object_finder_service.rb:119:in `block in process_my_object_link'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/active_com_my_object_finder_service.rb:109:in `each'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/active_com_my_object_finder_service.rb:109:in `process_my_object_link'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_my_object_finder_service.rb:29:in `block in process_data'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_my_object_finder_service.rb:28:in `each'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/abstract_my_object_finder_service.rb:28:in `process_data'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/run_crawlers_service.rb:18:in `block in run_all_crawlers'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.2.7.1/lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
/Users/davea/Documents/workspace/myproject/app/services/run_crawlers_service.rb:5:in `run_all_crawlers'
```

How do I avoid this error without changing the content of the string?  If PostGres is able to save this data, that’s the only thing I care about.  I do not know in advance what type of encoding the value of “name” will be when I write to it.  I can modify the PostGres column data type if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You have created your database with UTF-8 encoding. For more info check this [PostgreSQL Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-createdatabase.html)

You can use [charlock_holmes](https://github.com/brianmario/charlock_holmes) gem for character encoding detection and conversion or select proper encoding for your database.